# GRUB boot detection failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, grub2, ubuntu-20.04

I updated my image to ubuntu 20.04 from 16.04 and as a part of it upgraded grub to grub2. From the syslog, I am observing the following errors:

```
Oct 19 10:30:10 host-1 systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Oct 19 10:30:10 host-1 grub-editenv[533]: /usr/bin/grub-editenv: error: cannot open `/boot/grub/grubenv.new': No such file or directory.
Oct 19 10:30:10 host-1 systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 19 10:30:10 host-1 systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 19 10:30:10 host-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start GRUB failed boot detection.
```

How can I fix the same ?

Contents of my grub partition:

```
/boot/grub# ls
device.map  fonts  gfxblacklist.txt  grub.cfg grubenv  grub-mkconfig_lib  grub-multi-install  i386-pc  unicode.pf2
```